# Issue with photoresistor - the analogRead stays pretty much the same?

Tags: sensors

**UPDATE:** If I could **I'd downvote myself**. I'm a web developer and as I see that my job will be eaten, I'm trying to expand my skill set. Sometimes I wish I had a second pair of eyes or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

---

Previously I was asking which sensor use to measure the light: [Which sensor to detect light?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29758/which-sensor-to-detect-light)

Here is a short video showcasing my issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGs_Ax_wlbg

Super simple .INO sketch from https://tkkrlab.nl/wiki/Arduino_KY-018_Photo_resistor_module

```c++
int sensorPin = A5; // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int ledPin = 13; // select the pin for the LED
int sensorValue = 0; // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(sensorValue);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(sensorValue);
  Serial.println(sensorValue, DEC);
}
```

I'm worried that my sensor readings are pretty much the same - in shade, brighten up by green laser...

**Am I doing it right?**

**Are values from the sensor in the expected range?**

Alternatively: is there any more sensitive sensor I should buy that will tell me more reliably if the there is green laser light pointing at it?

Comment: It helps if you plug the sensor into ANALOG 5, not into DIGITAL 5 ...

Comment: :) It helps... Thank you for being second pair of eyes and sanity check here!

Comment: Could you place a filter on the sensor to block out the non green light?
What are the values you are getting and what do you think they should be?

Answer (score 1):

***** ITS ANALOG 5 not DIGITAL 5 *****

Also try doing this:

```
delay(sensorValue*10);
```

The times 10 will help show the differences between each value.

Comment: It looks like he is using an LDR breakout. Those probably already have a resistor.

Comment: True, my bad. There is a 10k k smd tinynynynyny resistor on it. No external resistor needed.

Comment: OMG! **ANALOG**... So silly, that's why I need second pair of eyes (and some common sense)...